# UIAlertController with text field - hitting return button only hides keyboard, does not perform action?

Tags: ios8, uialertcontroller

I'm trying to use the iOS 8 `UIAlertController` in place of where I would have used a `UIAlertView` in the past. I want the user to be able to enter text into this alert and hit "OK" to process the text or "Cancel" to cancel.

Here's the basic code:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Change Value" message:@"Enter your new value."];
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:nil];

[alert addAction: [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    UITextField *textField = alert.textFields[0];
    NSLog(@"text was %@", textField.text);
}]];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
    NSLog(@"Cancel pressed");
}]];

[presentingVC presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With the old `UIAlertView`, I would tag it with an `alertViewStyle` of `UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput`. Then, if the user hit the "Return" button on their keyboard after entering text, the UIAlertViewDelegate method `willDismissWithButtonIndex:` would be called with some `buttonIndex` (depending on what buttons had been specified in the `UIAlertView`).

In the new `UIAlertController`, if the user taps the "OK" or "Cancel" buttons, then their corresponding actions are performed as expected; but if the user just hits the "Return" key on the keyboard, it just hides the keyboard, but the alert remains on screen and no action is performed.

I've thought about configuring the text field to set the `UITextFieldDelegate` to `self`, and then maybe overriding the `textFieldDidReturn:` method, but I also don't know if there's a way to call one of the `UIAlertController`'s actions programmatically. And this is sounding sort of messy/hacky anyway. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I can't find a way to trigger actions programatically either. What an oversight...

Answer (score 9):

On iOS 9.3, this happens when you have multiple actions with `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` style.

When you add one action with `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` and another one with`UIAlertActionStyleCancel`, the action with default style will be called

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but there's been a simple solution around since iOS9 that I didn't see listed here, so hopefully this will help others.

It is true, that when you have multiple `UIAlertActionStyleDefault` actions, the system can't choose which one to trigger when the user presses the enter key in the `UITextField`.

However, you can set the `preferredAction` property on the UIAlertController to remedy this.

Therefore:

```
myAlertController.preferredAction = myDefaultAction;
```

Pressing enter in the UITextField will now trigger your chosen UIAlertAction.

Answer (score 1):

Not the ideal answer, but I ended up extracting my action's code into a method, and simply calling that method from both the action and the `textFieldDidReturn:` method in the `UITextFieldDelegate`.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    [self doAction:textField];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in iOS 8.0.2, it may have fixed it.  My text field is triggering the default "OK" action without even using any delegation.

Comment: Doesn't even work in iOS 9.2. This is definitely an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3 solution:

Make sure that you have only one option as .default. I also found out that the same misbehaviour arises when using one .default and one .destructive option... not sure why this happens.

```
let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Discard", style: .cancel) { (_) -> Void in
            self.invokedPullToAdd = false
        }
let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: .default) { [unowned ac] _ in
            let answer = ac.textFields![0]
            if answer.text != "" {
                self.addItem(name: answer.text!)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print ("WARNING: No input!")
            }
            self.invokedPullToAdd = false
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't set two "UIAlertActionStyleCancel" in UIAlertAction.